# How to get R class from other project?

Tags: android, resources, r.java-file

I would like to get acess to resources id's from other project but NOT by importing R class to to my file but dynamicaly. I would like to have a function with context parameter and get R class from it dynamically. Is it possible? The reason I am asking is I want to achieve similar effect to facebook api library. What they do is you add facebok_app_id string to your project and the library "somehow" gets it.

Comment: Pass the context and call getResources on that context.

Comment: Could'nt you use `getResources()` with the `packageName.R.whateveryouwant`?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the R from other projects. If its from the same project and different package you can use it by importing that.

```
import com.yourpackage.R;
```

Comment: Yes but is there any way to do it without knowing "com.yourpackage" name?

Answer (score 0):

you can also move all your graphics into another project and then make that project a library.  Then you can add that new project as a library dependency.  This way all your projects could share the graphics just by adding a library dependency.